# How to update StatefulWidget page from another StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to set the attribute todaysMood from another page whenever the list is tap here is my first page i used navigator pushnamed to go from another page

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> with AfterLayoutMixin<Home> {
   int todaysMood = 5;
   int userType = 0; 
  }
```

and here my second page

```
class AssessState extends State<Assess> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final Questions args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
 // TODO: implement build
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Assess"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: args.questions.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(args.questions[index]) ,
          onTap: () {
           //update attributes in first page here
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Jay's answer is acceptable but it is not the right way i think, consider about using app state/global state. you can use any of statemanagement tools on pub.dev like provider,rx, bloc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to change userType from AssessState class,

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> with AfterLayoutMixin<Home> {
   int todaysMood = 5;
   int userType = 0; 

   changeUserType(int type){
         setState((){
            userType = 1;
         });
   }
}
```

Pass the changeUserType() function when you are using Assess() widget like,

```
Assess(changeUserType);
```

Now, fetch the changeUserType function as an argument in your constructor.

```
class Assess extends StatefulWidget {
  const Assess(Function changeUserType);

  @override
  AssessState createState() => AssessState();
}

class AssessState extends State<Assess> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final Questions args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
 // TODO: implement build
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Assess"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: args.questions.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(args.questions[index]) ,
          onTap: () {
           //update attributes in first page here
           widget.changeUserType(1);
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }
 }
```

This way by passing function as an argument you can change or control states of other classes.

Answer (score 0):

The goal you want to achieve can be done with the State Management techniques of Flutter.I can recommend you to use `BLOC` .You can change any active Stateful widgets state in the application from anywhere.You can get [the full documentation here](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1)

Comment: You can check the complete document... It's a whole architecture